# Rails 4: how to integrate payumoney gateway in rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, payment-gateway, payumoney

i am using ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-linux]
and 
Rails 4.2.5.

kindly help me. i searched but did not find any solution

Answer (score 0):

Visit https://www.payumoney.com/payment-gateway-integration-guide.html

There is a section towards the bottom about Custom integrations - including a download link for a Rails application

[Download link for Rails sample app and Guide](https://github.com/payumoney-india/PUM_ROR/archive/master.zip)

There is a technical integration document with it, and maybe that in conjunction with the lib code itself could help.

There is also a Rails 3 example here: https://github.com/payu-india/PayU-Integration-Kit-ROR, which shouldn't take much to upgrade to Rails 4 and might give a clearer indication of what you need to do.

Additionally a quick search on The Ruby Toolbox also brings up lots of results, which may help you in your research:

[The Ruby Toolbox: Payu](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=payu)

Comment: i downloaded it ..but it has no documentation on how to use that gem.

Comment: Updated my solution - maybe it will help.